# Fair and biased coins

Tags: probability

Let's suppose we have $25$ coins: $14$ fair (F) and $11$ biased (B) with heads on both sides. We draw one coin, throw it, and repeat it ten times (with replacement). Calculate proability, that we get only heads.

So, at first I thought I can simply list all the possible outcomes with respect to biased coins, so $0$ biased, $1$ biased, $2$ biased, ..., $10$ biased, but it takes some time, and I guess it's not the best approach. What's more, I should permute all of the outcomes, as I can have, for example, for two biased coins, sequences $BBFFFFFFFF$ or $FBFFFFFBFF$ or assume, that order doesn't matter.

Comment: Try to see what is the probability $p$ that you get heads in *one* throw. Then your answer should be $p^{10}$ for $10$ throws, because all the throws are independent from each other.

Comment: @StinkingBishop so it's $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{14}{25}+1\cdot \frac{11}{25}= \frac{18}{25}$

Answer (score 2):

Probability of picking biased coin $ = \frac{11}{25}$

Probability of picking fair coin $ = \frac{14}{25}$

Probability of getting head in a flip $ = \frac{11}{25} + \frac{14}{25} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{18}{25}$

For $10$ heads in a row, the probability is $(\frac{18}{25})^{10}$.